# Why Javascript POST Request to ASP.NET controller action getting NULL parameter?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

The parameters of my ASP .NET controller method stays null when I send a `XmlHttpRequets` from my JavaScript file. The JavaScript debugger shows that the request sends successfully. Why is It not working?

**JavaScript function:**

```
function BuyBook(title) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "home/BuyBook", true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    var order = { BookTitle: title, Quantity: document.getElementById("quantity").value };
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify({ order: order }));
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

**Controller method:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult BuyBook(Models.Order order)
        { .... }
```

**Models.Order class:**

```
public class Order
    {
        [Required]
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }

        [Range(1,100)]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How does your `Models.Order` class looks like ? The issue might be that the JSON you are sending is not exactly matching the signature of the class.

Comment: Also, you are not sending the multipart/form-data .... so use `application/json` - `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: @AdityaBhave I have Edited my post

Comment: Does the API call fires the `BuyBook` method??

Comment: @Hadi Yes it does, when I check the network tab in the debugger. It shows that it successfully sends an object with "order" as key value. I have a screenshot of the Request result: https://imgur.com/15C2XXv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following things:

1. Check that the class signature matches the JSON being sent. For above example, the JSON being sent would look like

   ```
   { "BookTitle": title, "Quantity": "value" }
   ```
2. Also I see that the class defines `Quantity` as `int`, so use `parseInt()` to convert `Quantity` value into `int`. By default `document.getElementById(..).value` would give a string.

   ```
   let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
   var order = { BookTitle: title, Quantity: quantity };
   ```
3. Use `Content-Type` as `application/json`
4. Add `[FromBody]` attribute to the `model`

   ```
   BuyBook([FromBody]Models.Order order)
   ```
5. Send the order object like below.

   ```
   xmlHttp.send(order);
   ```

   OR

   ```
   xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(order));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Update your method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BuyBook([FromBody] Models.Order order)
{ .... }
```

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#frombody-attribute)

Comment: Try to change the line `xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify({ order: order }));` as     `xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(order));`